# Messing with JAX-RS SSE : Could not find a suitable constructor in javax.ws.rs.sse.SseEventSink class

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I am currently trying to experiment in a webproject with SSE. I had to update, and enable asynchronous support. However, a simple 'GET' request to the 'subscribe' endpoint throws an error, even if done with the browser.

```
@Path("/subscribe")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
public void subscribe(@Context SseEventSink eSink) {
    sinkList.add(eSink);
}
```

If I am just entering request with the browser is this incorrect? Is this a compatibility issue? how else do I test SSE connections as compared with websockets which have a client? So far I know that the SseEventSinks cannot be created with a constructor. I am a bit over my head with this

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Summarized error/warning logs thrown below.

> WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: HK2
>   service reification failed for [javax.ws.rs.sse.SseEventSink] with an
>   exception: MultiException stack 1 of 2
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor
>   in javax.ws.rs.sse.SseEventSink class.    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:192)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getConstructor(Utilities.java:180)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:129)
>
> ...
>
> at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) MultiException stack 2 of 2
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while
>   reifying SystemDescriptor(
>     implementation=javax.ws.rs.sse.SseEventSink
>     contracts={javax.ws.rs.sse.SseEventSink}
>     scope=org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped
>     qualifiers={}   descriptorType=CLASS    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
>     metadata=   rank=0  loader=null     proxiable=null
>     proxyForSameScope=null  analysisName=null   id=198  locatorId=0
>     identityHashCode=282776705  reified=false)  at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:705)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:464)
>
> ...
>
> WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for
>   [javax.ws.rs.sse.SseEventSink] with an exception: MultiException stack
>   1 of 2 java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable
>   constructor in javax.ws.rs.sse.SseEventSink class.    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:192)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getConstructor(Utilities.java:180)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:129)
>
> ...
>
> at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) MultiException stack 2 of 2
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while
>   reifying SystemDescriptor(
>     implementation=javax.ws.rs.sse.SseEventSink
>     contracts={javax.ws.rs.sse.SseEventSink}
>     scope=org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped
>
> ...
>
> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in
>   context with path [/Api] threw exception
>   [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SseEventSink parameter detected,
>   but not found.] with root cause java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   SseEventSink parameter detected, but not found.   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$SseEventSinkInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:159)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
>
> ... at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: `SseEventSink` is an interface, you might need to use an implementation instead

Comment: It seems like so, only thing is that throws me off is that none of the tutorial implementations seem to mention that step in applying SSE. I feel I am using a different JAX-RS or something?

IE: https://www.baeldung.com/java-ee-jax-rs-sse

Comment: I am actually looking at that now in preparation of an interview, I realise my answer was bogus. And actually, I am having the same issue as you. I'll remove my answer for now and post an other one if I ever find how to get it to work.

Comment: I updated my answer with what worked for me. A missing dependency

Comment: @Bentaye IT works! Magical! Fantastic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and got it working by adding the **jersey-media-sse** dependency to my pom.xml (using Maven)

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-sse -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using Maven here is [the link to the repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-sse/)

I am not sure, but as far as I understand, the problem is that `SseEventSink` is an interface and Jersey can't instanciate any class for it. The dependency above probably provides a default implementation and a default mapper for the `SseEventSink` interface

Comment: Thanks!

Just tried it, it doesn't seem to do the trick for this, it seems to throw the same error. Something that also keeps throwing me off is that in all the tutorials about using SSE, none of them really mention using an implementation for the SseEventSink.or include anything similar in their github examples.